# What is the ‘Pile-up Problem’?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, trend

In methods of trend-cycle decomposition, what is meant by the *'pile up problem'*? How can the pile up problem be detected? Can it be detected by the method of visual inspection? If so, what are the signs that suggest the problem is present?

The pile up problem is something that I've heard about through verbal discussions, but I'd like a proper explanation. My current understanding, which is admittedly a bit vague, is that the problem relates to cases where the cyclical component is small - relative to the trend component - and appears to be high frequency noise.

Comment: While I can't provide a proper explanation, [this paper](http://econ.washington.edu/files/2013/10/Kim_jmpaper2.pdf) seems to present a good introduction and discussion of the pile-up problem and related topics. I also find an explanation in [this econometrics paper](http://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/feds/2001/200108/200108pap.pdf) easy to digest (pp. 5-6).